# Could not really install apk successfully via command line

Tags: android, adb

Pixel 3XL could not install app via adb but could using AS run to install the app
I use the command line to install the apk and it said it is successfuly. But I could not see the icon in the launcher. Plus, when I try to list the installed apk, it is not in the list.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:~ zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep `common_string_in_package_name_with_installed_app_package`
package:A
package:B
package:C
package:D
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:~ zgong$ adb install XXXX.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:~ zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep `common_string_in_package_name_with_installed_app_package`
package:A
package:B
package:C
package:D
```

No new package is installed.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:~ zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep `unique string_in_package_name`
```

No new package is installed.

It is so weird that this issue happens.

I could use adb to install the apk for other Android device.
I am using Android 4.0.1.

Anyone know how to fix it?

**Update 1:**

The commen says that adb install is the wrapper of `adb shell pm install`.
I run the `adb shell pm` to get the manual of options.
It seems that there are no options which could help to debug.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:android_vdca zgong$ adb shell pm
Package manager (package) commands:
  help
    Print this help text.



  install [-rtfdgw] [-i PACKAGE] [--user USER_ID|all|current]
       [-p INHERIT_PACKAGE] [--install-location 0/1/2]
       [--install-reason 0/1/2/3/4] [--originating-uri URI]
       [--referrer URI] [--abi ABI_NAME] [--force-sdk]
       [--preload] [--instant] [--full] [--dont-kill]
       [--enable-rollback]
       [--force-uuid internal|UUID] [--pkg PACKAGE] [-S BYTES]
       [--apex] [--wait TIMEOUT]
       [PATH [SPLIT...]|-]
    Install an application.  Must provide the apk data to install, either as
    file path(s) or '-' to read from stdin.  Options are:
      -R: disallow replacement of existing application
      -t: allow test packages
      -i: specify package name of installer owning the app
      -f: install application on internal flash
      -d: allow version code downgrade (debuggable packages only)
      -p: partial application install (new split on top of existing pkg)
      -g: grant all runtime permissions
      -S: size in bytes of package, required for stdin
      --user: install under the given user.
      --dont-kill: installing a new feature split, don't kill running app
      --restrict-permissions: don't whitelist restricted permissions at install
      --originating-uri: set URI where app was downloaded from
      --referrer: set URI that instigated the install of the app
      --pkg: specify expected package name of app being installed
      --abi: override the default ABI of the platform
      --instant: cause the app to be installed as an ephemeral install app
      --full: cause the app to be installed as a non-ephemeral full app
      --install-location: force the install location:
          0=auto, 1=internal only, 2=prefer external
      --install-reason: indicates why the app is being installed:
          0=unknown, 1=admin policy, 2=device restore,
          3=device setup, 4=user request
      --force-uuid: force install on to disk volume with given UUID
      --apex: install an .apex file, not an .apk
      --wait: when performing staged install, wait TIMEOUT milliseconds
          for pre-reboot verification to complete. If TIMEOUT is not
          specified it will wait for 60000 milliseconds.
```

**Update 2:**

copy the apk to the device:

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:android_vdca zgong$ adb push ~/Downloads/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk /storage/emulated/0/Download/
/Users/zgong/Downloads/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk: 1 file pushed. 12.7 MB/s (34493209 bytes in 2.597s)
```

use `pm install` via adb shell

```
255|crosshatch:/storage/emulated/0/Download $ pm install NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
avc:  denied  { read } for  scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:fuse:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
System server has no access to read file context u:object_r:fuse:s0 (from path /storage/emulated/0/Download/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk, context u:r:system_server:s0)
Error: Unable to open file: NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
Consider using a file under /data/local/tmp/
Error: Can't open file: NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk

Exception occurred while executing 'install':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Can't open file: NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:519)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doRunInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1282)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1248)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:184)
    at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21605)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4603)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4306)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

**Update 3**

```
crosshatch:/ $ cp /storage/emulated/0/Download/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk /data/local/tmp/apk1.apk
\crosshatch:/ $ ls -la /data/local/tmp
total 51656
drwxrwx--x 4 shell shell     3488 2020-11-19 10:13 .
drwxr-x--x 4 root  root      3488 2019-11-19 14:53 ..
drwxrwxrwx 4 shell shell     3488 2020-11-10 13:55 .studio
-rw-rw---- 1 shell shell 34493209 2020-11-19 10:13 apk1.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 shell shell  4322329 1970-01-01 08:00 apk1592483766800.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 shell shell  4808820 1970-01-01 08:00 apk1597806836158.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 shell shell  4808820 1970-01-01 08:00 apk1597807282659.apk
-rw-rw-rw- 1 shell shell  4375675 1970-01-01 08:00 apk1599201485983.apk
drwxrwxrwx 5 shell shell     3488 2020-11-02 00:17 perfd
-rw-rw-rw- 1 shell shell        8 1970-01-01 08:00 vysor.pwd
crosshatch:/ $ pm install /data/local/tmp/ap
apk1.apk              apk1592483766800.apk  apk1597806836158.apk  apk1597807282659.apk  apk1599201485983.apk
crosshatch:/ $ pm install /data/local/tmp/apk1.apk
Success
crosshatch:/ $ exit
```

To verify if it is installed for real

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:android_vdca zgong$ /Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt2 dump packagename ~/Downloads/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
com.nonsimcc.vmcp
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:android_vdca zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep vmcp
```

It still failed to be installed for real.

**Update 4**

I have tried to reboot my Pixel 3XL device. Still bad luck.

**Update 5**

Just tested and the get the weird result:

Android Studio, click Run, and the app could be installed and launched.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
package:com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
```

In Run section in Android Studio

```
11/19 11:51:07: Launching 'demoApp' on Google Pixel 3 XL.
Install successfully finished in 1 s 290 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo/com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo.DemoActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 27798 on device 'google-pixel_3_xl-8BBY0WYAG'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
```

Using the same apk built from Run, and use `adb install`

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb install -t demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
```

**What is the difference between `adb install` and Android Studio installation process?**

**Update 6:**

Already tried to Revoke USB debugging authorizations
Still bad luck.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb install -t demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apkPerforming Streamed Install
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
```

Also tried to close the Developer options and reopened it.
Set the USB Preferences - USE USB FOR, choose PTP or No data transfer.
Still bad luck

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb install -t demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apkPerforming Streamed Install
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
```

**Update 7:**
[image: Android OS version]

I noticed that there is an OS update for me to do.

[image: Android update to be done]

**Update 7**

"adb install" does not work when installing to the emulator due to unmatching abi

I create a AVD

```
Name: Pixel_3_XL_API_Q

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: /Users/zgong/.android/avd/Pixel_3_XL_API_Q.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level Q)

Skin: pixel_3_xl

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_3_xl

hw.lcd.width: 1440

image.androidVersion.codename: Q

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 28

tag.id: google_apis

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 3 XL API Q

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 8192

PlayStore.enabled: false

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 2960

vm.heapSize: 4096

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-Q/google_apis/x86/

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

AvdId: Pixel_3_XL_API_Q

hw.lcd.density: 560

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:9bbaa408d4a8691920c4057ef7844f35

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: no

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 40G

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

I tried to install the same apk built from Android Studio.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb -e install -t -r demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

**Update 8:**
"adb install" work when installing to another device

So I use the same build to install it on another Pixel 3 device. It can be installed correctly.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb -d install -t demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
```

[image: Working device Pixel 3 device info]

In this way, we exclude the suspect of the build.

**Update 9:**

On Pixel 3XL on which it does not work before:

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ /Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt2 dump packagename demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk
com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo


WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb -d uninstall com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb install demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk
error: more than one device/emulator
Performing Push Install
adb: error: failed to get feature set: more than one device/emulator
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb -d install demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb -d install -t demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep visaerror: more than one device/emulator
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb -d shell cmd package list packages | grep com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
package:com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
```

And now I could see the icon in Launcher and could launch the app. So amazing.

Comment: Hi Francis. I don't know. But 'adb install' is a wrapper for the command 'pm install' that can be run locally on the device via 'adb shell'. When you install the package directly, you can pass in more command line options and receive additional output. Does the problem only happen for this APK or all APKs?

Comment: @Elletlar I check the `adb shell pm install`, which options do you say could help fix the issue? The problem happens for the other APK as well.

Comment: Nothing in particular, I thought you might see some additional output inside 'adb shell' if you copy the APK file to the device then run 'pm install' directly instead of doing 'adb  install'. I can you send you my procedure for doing it if you want most of the StackOverflow posts describing it no longer work.

Comment: But regarding your issue, I would probably be trying the same things that you have likely already tried: Rebooting the phone and restarting ADB, Playing with the 'Developer Options' under the device settings, Ensuring any 'Untrusted Sources' settings are set to allowed, Making sure the Manifest has a MAIN and LAUNCHER, Check the notification tray for any pending install permission requests etc

Comment: Regarding the new error message, I always 'cp' the APK to '/data/local/tmp' as that error message recommends. Installing from there works under normal circumstances.

Comment: I cannot wait to see how this story ends :) :) :)

Comment: @Elletlar Me too. Android Studio should use adb shell pm install to install the apk. Should be no difference.

Comment: Only things I am wondering. Does doing "adb uninstall <package-name>" first make any difference. Does "adb install" work when installing to the emulator or another device. Does "adb install" work with a 3rd party .apk not built in your environment. Does it work if you disable proguard in the APK, turn off minify in Gradle etc. Does issuing kill and restart on adb help...

Comment: @Elletlar the build is correct, plz check Update 8. So maybe it is a Android OS issue? But it is confirmed that I can use Android Studio install the apk so it is against the conclusion above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed when uninstalling the apk (`adb uninstall`) and then execute the `adb install` again

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:Downloads zgong$ adb -d install ~/Downloads/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:Downloads zgong$ /Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt2 dump packagename ~/Downloads/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
com.nonsimcc.vmcp
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:Downloads zgong$ adb -d shell cmd package list packages | grep com.nonsimcc.vmcp
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:Downloads zgong$ adb uninstall com.nonsimcc.vmcp
error: more than one device/emulator
- waiting for device -
error: more than one device/emulator
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:Downloads zgong$ adb -d uninstall com.nonsimcc.vmcp
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:Downloads zgong$ adb -d shell cmd package list packages | grep com.nonsimcc.vmcp
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:Downloads zgong$ adb -d install ~/Downloads/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:Downloads zgong$ adb -d shell cmd package list packages | grep com.nonsimcc.vmcp
package:com.nonsimcc.vmcp
```

Comment: Great! :) People have on occasion brought phones to me saying that uninstalling via the UI was not removing the app fully. In these cases, they couldn't install the APK even though nothing was available to uninstall under 'settings -> apps'. But really 'adb install' should be reporting a failure if it cannot complete the process...Another thing that might help is doing a 'replace' via 'adb install -r'. It should install the APK even if one already exists with the same version number. It is also a decent approximation of updating from the playstore when that needs to be simulated.

Comment: Agreed.Guess we need more further investigation on what is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build then build bundle(s) / APK(s) then build APK

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the issue is focusing on what if I only have the apk.