# Faild to install apk via `adb install` - what is the deep difference between adb install and Android Studio install

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Android Studio, click Run, and the app could be installed and launched.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
package:com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
```

In Run section in Android Studio

```
11/19 11:51:07: Launching 'demoApp' on Google Pixel 3 XL.
Install successfully finished in 1 s 290 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo/com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo.DemoActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 27798 on device 'google-pixel_3_xl-8BBY0WYAG'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
```

Using the same apk built from Run, and use adb install

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb install -t demoApp/build/outputs/apk/classic/debug/demoApp-classic-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
```

However, the app is not in the package list.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:mep_login_android zgong$ adb shell cmd package list packages | grep com.visa.mobileEnablement.loginFeatureDemo
```

What is the difference between adb install and Android Studio installation process?

Comment: and what happens if you execute `adb shell cmd package list packages`? empty list?

Comment: Nope, if excluding the grep coammnd, there are many apps in the list except the one I try to install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not really install apk successfully via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890875/could-not-really-install-apk-successfully-via-command-line)

Comment: @Lino Unfortunately not.